# Typescript - This expression is not callable on MUI

Tags: typescript

I am adding TypeScript on an existing project.

I got stuck here:
Old code:

```
    <Box style={{ ...styledBox(isCurrentUser) }}>


===
export const styledBox = ({ isCurrentUser }) => {
  return {
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: isCurrentUser ? "row-reverse" : "row",
    zIndex: -1,
  };
};
```

New code:

```
    <Box sx={{...styledBox(isCurrentUser) }}>


===
import { SxProps } from "@mui/system";

interface StyledBoxType {
  isCurrentUser: boolean;
}

export const styledBox: SxProps<StyledBoxType> = ({
  isCurrentUser,
}) => {
  return {
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: isCurrentUser ? "row-reverse" : "row",
    zIndex: -1,
  };
};
```

At the beginning it wasn't accepti `sx`. Now it's all ok.
However there is still an error on the destructurization of `...styledBox`

It is saying:
This expression is not callable.

```
  Not all constituents of type 'SystemCssProperties<StyledBoxType> | CSSPseudoSelectorProps<StyledBoxType> | CSSSelectorObject<StyledBoxType> | ((theme: StyledBoxType) => SystemStyleObject<...>) | (boolean | ... 1 more ... | ((theme: StyledBoxType) => SystemStyleObject<...>))[]' are callable.
    Type 'SystemCssProperties<StyledBoxType>' has no call signatures.ts(2349)
Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'null'.ts(2721)
(alias) const styledBox: SxProps<StyledBoxType>
import styledBox
```

Can anyone help me understand and fix this error?

**EDIT:**

As suggested in a comment I changed it to:

```
export const styledBox: (props: StyledBoxType) => SxProps = ({
  isCurrentUser,
}) => {
  return {
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: isCurrentUser ? "row-reverse" : "row",
    zIndex: -1,
  };
};
```

However now aligned is the argument `isCurrentUser` here: `<Box sx={{ ...styledBox(isCurrentUser) }}>`:
Argument of type 'boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'StyledBoxType'.ts(2345)

Comment: The `SxProps` seems to be the returned styles and not the function type.  

Can you try to set the type to `(props: StyledBoxType) => SxProps` instead of  `SxProps<StyledBoxType>`

Comment: @DidiBear Thank you. I updated the original question. Now `isCurrentUser` is not typed

Comment: I think this is because you must use `styledBox({ isCurrentUser })` instead of `styledBox(isCurrentUser)`, so that it's an object of type `StyledBoxType`.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```js
<Box sx={{
  display: "flex",
  flexDirection: isCurrentUser ? "row-reverse" : "row",
  zIndex: -1,
}}>
```

> Type 'SystemCssProperties' has no call signatures

This tells me this has to go inline without calling into another function. Assuming you still want to use the `SxProps<StyledBoxType>` type.

Comment: I would like to keep the structure. So the styles will be in a different file as it is now. Now  `styledBox` is in a different file exported.... Is that possible to avoid putting the inline style in `sx` and just import the style from a different file, together with the `isCurrentUser` variable?

Comment: I think so but the signature cannot be a function call. You might be able to pass in a simple boolean then return the type.